# How can I make my Firebase database only accessible from my own Android app?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I have a Firestore database and an Android app that connects with it. I want my app only to read from the database; the app is not going to write or delete anything from it. I also don't need any users or authentication by passwords. I just want my app to access a few collections and display them in GUI. In the rules, I put this:

```
allow list;
```

However, if I understand it correctly, it is possible for other people to access my database/integrate it into their apps and use for their own purposes. How can I avoid this? I want my database only be accessible from my app + I don't need users to authenticate by typing their username/password...
If I include anonymous authentication, then how does it solve the problem if another person can do the same thing with it to access my database, i.e. come up with a code that uses anonymous authentication to access my DB?

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/support/privacy/storing-privacy-settings see this

Comment: It's not possible.  User auth is the only way to restrict access to Firestore from a web or mobile app.